# Expression is not an integer constant expression in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing this in my code and it is giving me this error: Expression is not an integer constant expression

Code:

```
//Tag for Database
#define kInsertIntoDatabase            @"Insert"
#define kDeleteFromDatabase            @"Delete"
#define kUpdateIntoDatabase            @"Update"
#define kQueryDatabase                 @"Query"


-(void)documentIsReady:(NSString *)sqlmethod{
    if(document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)
    {
        context = document.managedObjectContext;
    }

    switch (sqlmethod) {
        case kInsertIntoDatabase:
            [self insertCoreDataModel];
            break;
        case kDeleteFromDatabase:
            [self deleteCoreDataModel];
            break;
        case kUpdateIntoDatabase:
            [self updateCoreDataModel];
            break;
        case kDeleteFromDatabase:
            [self deleteCoreDataModel];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

What is wrong? Not sure what is wrong. Need some guidance...

Comment: What it said.  The `case` values must be integer constants.  Yours aren't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use the switch, you should go for an enum, that will let you keep something readable while integers for the switch.

try this out :

```
typedef enum {
    DatabaseMainFunctions_InsertIntoDatabase,
    DatabaseMainFunctions_DeleteFromDatabase,
    DatabaseMainFunctions_UpdateInto,
    DatabaseMainFunctions_Query
}DatabaseMainFunctions;
```

then something like

```
switch (sqlmethod) {
    case DatabaseMainFunctions_InsertIntoDatabase:
        [self insertCoreDataModel];
        break;
    case DatabaseMainFunctions_DeleteFromDatabase:
        [self deleteCoreDataModel];
        break;
    case DatabaseMainFunctions_UpdateInto:
        [self updateCoreDataModel];
        break;
    case DatabaseMainFunctions_Query:
        [self deleteCoreDataModel];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

watch out, your case delete is written two times in your example, probably some copy paste mistake.

**There is an objective c switch on github** from Nicolas Bouilleaud that is **made for strings** (actually objects) : [objcswitch](https://github.com/n-b/objcswitch)

Comment: Actually, objcswitch is more an experimental implementation than something you should use. In particular, the declaration of the case: methods is really hacky, and not something you want to see in code you'd have to maintain. (But I'm glad you found it!)

Comment: Also, there's an ongoing discussion on this subject on http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2013/Apr/msg00000.html

Comment: @n-b : hehe, saw it on the french cocoaheads mailing list a while ago and had it in mind from that time. (I'm glad you did it ;)

Answer (score 4):

In a switch statement, you can use **integer constant expressions only** as labels. No floating-point numbers, no structs, no pointers, no objects, nothing. Just integer constants. If you want to make decisions based on `NSString` equality, you will need to use nesting `if-else` statements:

```
if ([sqlmethod isEqualToString:kInsertIntoDatabase]) {
    // do stuff
} else if ([sqlmethod isEqualToString:kDeleteFromDatabase]) {
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All these

```
#define kInsertIntoDatabase            @"Insert"
#define kDeleteFromDatabase            @"Delete"
#define kUpdateIntoDatabase            @"Update"
#define kQueryDatabase                 @"Query"
```

are `NSString`, and `case` needs `integer`,

Your code is converted into

```
case @"Insert":
```

which is a syntactical/syntax error of `switch-case` statement.